# Unnecessary Constructor in FileDialog?

Tags: java, inheritance, constructor, filedialog

Can someone please explain to me **why does `FileDialog` implements two constructors, one for Frame and one for Dialog?** I mean, why didn't they use the blessings of inheritance and just created a constructor using `Window`? I ask this because sometimes when you need to request a file using a GUI, you could request a file from a `Frame` or from a `Dialog` and it would be good if you don't have to worry about creating your "requester" method for a `Frame` and also for a `Dialog`, I took a look at the source code of `FileDialog`, and there is no difference (that I could appreciate) between the constructors, since they only use the `Frame` and `Dialog` to establish them as the `parentComponent`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those constructions were created at different times in history. There is a strong, forcible need for backward compatibility.

```
// @since 1.5
public FileDialog(Dialog parent)

// @since JDK1.1
public FileDialog(Frame parent)
```

Comment: aaaa so that is the reason... interesting, couldn´t they also add a constructor for window ¬.¬, I need one of those :(... thanks for your answer :)...

Comment: @Ordiel - Create a new question concerning that need.  But I think the answer is going to be   FileDialog fd = new FileDialog(Frame(null));  (or  new FileDialog(new Frame()) ) - both cause an application modal dialog to pop (in my quick test).  But better to post the new question to see what others think.